# cd in PowerShell to, cd plus ls

Tags: shell, powershell, scripting

How I can write a function or alias a command in PowerShell  so that cd can do two things:

1. cd the given dir
2. ls the dir content

EDIT:

What I need is this:

```
function ccd
{
    param($path)
    set-location $path 
    ls
}
```

but instead of ccd I want to write cd. When I change the function name to cd (from ccd) it changes the directory, but does not list the items in it :(. Seems that my cd function is being overridden.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You mean something like this?

```
function Set-LocationWithGCI{
    param(
            $path
         )
    if(Test-Path $path){
        $path = Resolve-Path $path
        Set-Location $path
        Get-ChildItem $path
    }else{
        "Could not find path $path"
    }
}
Set-Alias cdd Set-LocationWithGCI -Force
```

I see that you actually want to change the built-in cd alias. To do that, you would need to remove the existing one then create the new one:

```
Remove-Item alias:\cd
New-Alias cd Set-LocationWithGCI
```

Comment: This code does not work, and it has errors. And why you alias to ccd but not to cd???

Comment: Please see my edit section in my question for more clarifications.

Comment: Could you explain how it does not work? It worked fine for me. I set the alias as cdd so as to not overwrite the existing alias for cd.

Comment: The term 'ccd' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the n
ame, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:4
+ ccd <<<<  .\testdir
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (ccd:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: The alias that I set in the code is cdd **not** ccd. So yes, ccd would not be recognized.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I wanted to have. You could join "Remove-Item alias:\cd New-Alias cd Set-LocationWithGCI" with the actual answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'll add my two cents here, for future me and in case it might interest somebody.

In my_profile.ps1 :

```
function Set-LocationAndShowDir{
    param($path)
    try {
      Set-Location $path -ErrorAction Stop
      Get-ChildItem
    } catch {
      Write-Error $_
    }
}
Remove-Alias cd
Set-Alias cd Set-LocationAndShowDir -Force
```

This is inspired by @ebgreen answer, but will display the original error in case of failure, which feels more transparent.